# Delete images where image path is saved with path in database

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am uploading an image and while saving to the database I am adding path to the location along with the filename.

> eg : product/name/L4I84qXltYvCCDsAeQzi7fzZfKF3WTRa1LPOPGxj.jpeg

Why adding location where I can call them through asset()?
The table is also used by API application where it requires the url format like this.

**My Controller Cdde**

```
  //! Product Image
        if ($request->hasFile('product_image')) {
            $product_image = $request->file('product_image');
            $product_image_extension = $product_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $product_image_filename =  Str::slug($request->input('product_code')) .  '.' . Str::random(3) . "." . $product_image_extension;
            $product_image_location = public_path('assets/products/' . $product_image_filename);
            Image::make($product_image)->resize(300, 300)->save($product_image_location);
        }
```

---

```
Products::create([
//Other Fields 
            'image' => 'assets/products/' . $product_image_filename
        ]);
```

I am wondering how do I remove the image and add a new image

For comparison, I need the image file name. Since I am using the path, I am getting the path prefixed to the Image Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File 



$image_path = "/images/filename.ext";  // Value is not URL but directory file path
    if(File::exists($image_path)) {
        File::delete($image_path);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 use File; 

  @unlink(public_path() . 'uploads/documents/' . $users->document1);
```